# How to whitelist Google, Bing, Yahoo and popular browsers user-agent?

Tags: .htaccess

I know this may not be the best practice to dealing with the problem at hand, but please answer this question rather than trying to convince me of another strategy.

I want to develop a .htaccess file to block any visitors with user agents that DO NOT contain: Mozilla, googlebot, yahoo, bing, Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the rules using negation in `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Googlebot|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
```

Comment: What is that part about the IP addresses?

Comment: Sorry That was by mistake